# Writing view query for couchDB

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I have a number of docs with following structure.

```
{
_id:"",
url:"",
users_linked:[1,2,3...]
}
```

Whenever a user logs in I want to show him all URLs except those which are linked to hi, my map function does

```
 for(i in doc.users_linked){ emit(doc.users_linked[i],doc.url); }
```

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, given an user with id==USERID, you want the inverse of querying your view with `key=USERID`.

The only solution I know, is to do two queries to the view you provided:

- first get all "previous users" with: `endkey=USERID&inclusive_end=false`
- then get all "following users" with: `startkey=<USERID+1>`.

I'm assuming from your sample document that userids are numerical.

Comment: I figured out that this is the potential solution but doesnt it make the whole thing inefficient ?

Comment: It's hard to say without further details. The rule of thumb I use is: keep it as simple as possible, and design your app for change. Fix performance problems when they became problems.